# NuxtJS SPA mode (ssr false) still generates HTML for each vue file in the pages folder

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, single-page-application

The Nuxt documentation (latest) states that for SPA you need to set `ssr: false` in `nuxt.config.js`. Also, every vue file in the pages folder is added to the router configuration, so you don't have to do this yourself. This is both correct and works perfectly, but there is something I really don't understand.

When I run `npm run build` (nuxt-ts build), it builds the production output of the project and puts in the `dist` folder (default). I was surprised to see that even though I configured it to be a SPA, it still generates HTML files for each vue file in the `pages` folder.

It happens with newly generated projects using `npx nuxt-create-app` as well.

What I'd expect is that it only generates one HTML file (which is index) when `ssr` is set to `false` and when I want a static app, I would use `npm run generate` or set `target` to `'static'` to create HTML files per route.

Nuxt documentation also states this for the `target` property:

- https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/get-started/commands#target-server-default-value (builds output to dist)
- https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/get-started/commands#target-static (generates HTML per route)

All I have in my config is ssr set to false, so it should not generate static files (HTML) per page.
What am I missing here, or am I misunderstanding how this works?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that in a static setup, your visitors may arrive at your site via any of your page routes— not just index.html.

For example, they may access https://www.your-app.com/contact-us. If you do not have a contact-us.html file available, and you don’t have a server configured to handle this request (as is the case with universal mode), you’re gonna end up with a 404.

What happens in static mode is contact-us.html is served, which contains the minimum javascript necessary to hydrate your nuxt app, **then** SPA mode kicks in— giving you client-side navigation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I missed the part about the generated pages for deeplinking purposes in a SPA setup. Do you happen to know if there is any documentation available for this? Normally I would configure a fallback in my web.config, which will handle this for me and redirects all non-existent routes to /home.